# Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Diff Menu

Tags: nautilus, windows-subsystem-for-linux, 22.04

On system

```
> wsl --status
Default Distribution: Ubuntu
Default Version: 2
WSL version: 0.58.3.0
Kernel version: 5.10.102.1
WSLg version: 1.0.33
MSRDC version: 1.2.2924
Direct3D version: 1.601.0
Windows version: 10.0.22616.1
```

when nautilus is started (from command line) a continous list of these messages are shown:

```
(org.gnome.Nautilus:857): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:26:50.901: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Diff Menu...
```

How do I solve that **?**

Comment: Do you have anything in `~/Templates`?  See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489929/432493) on Unix & Linux for a similar issue.

Comment: There is no ~/Templates in my system.

Comment: (Oops, that previous comment got posted before I was ready).  Okay, not sure then. Not seeing this on my 22.04 installation where I just tried it out with Nautilus.  Is there anything else about your installation that you can provide?  Using any Systemd or launching Nautilus with dbus-launch?  Anything that can help me to reproduce?  Thanks!

Comment: The only Diff I can find in nautilus is the diff in rabbitGit